# Concatenating structs/arrays of different length in GBQ (SQL)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two different tables. This is the first one:

```
WITH
  source_data AS (
  SELECT
    'MMTT' AS client_id,
    CAST('2022-10-13' AS DATE) AS session_date,
    1 AS value,
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    'MMTT' AS client_id,
    CAST('2022-10-13' AS DATE) AS session_date,
    2 AS value,
        UNION ALL
    SELECT
    'MMTT' AS client_id,
    CAST('2022-10-13' AS DATE) AS session_date,
    3 AS value,
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'MMTT',
    CAST('2022-10-14' AS DATE),
    1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'MMTT',
    CAST('2022-10-14' AS DATE),
    2
      UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'MMTT',
    CAST('2022-10-14' AS DATE),
    3)

    select client_id, session_date, ARRAY_AGG( STRUCT(value)) AS value_info,
    from source_data
    GROUP BY 1,2
```

This is the output:

[image]

This is my second table:

```
WITH
  source_data AS (
  SELECT
    'MMTT' AS client_id,
    CAST('2022-10-13' AS DATE) AS session_date,
    'French' AS languages,
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    'MMTT' AS client_id,
    CAST('2022-10-13' AS DATE) AS session_date,
    'English'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'MMTT',
    CAST('2022-10-14' AS DATE),
    'French'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'MMTT',
    CAST('2022-10-14' AS DATE),
    'English'
)

    select client_id, session_date, ARRAY_AGG( STRUCT(languages)) AS languages_info,
    from source_data
    GROUP BY 1,2
```

With the following output:

[image]

I want to concatenate both arrays, but they have different length. If I do a join, of course it's duplicating records and it's not working.

This would be the expected output:

[image]

How can I achieve this result? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below

```
select client_id, session_date, 
  value_info,
  languages_info
from output_1
left join output_2
using(client_id, session_date)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! I just created the Arrays in different CTEs instead of doing it at the end and then performing the join left. This works!!